# How to write unit test my angular service which uses mergeMap()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I'm new to karma/jasmine framework.

I'm trying to add a test case to cover my service method(below)

```
public getAllChassis(): Observable<Chassis[]> {
      return this.http.get('chassis').pipe(
            mergeMap((result: Chassis[]) => {
               for (const chassis of result) {
                  chassis.healthStatus = 45;
                  chassis.complianceStatus = 81;
               }
               return of(result);
            }));
   }
```

which is not covering the callback/inside pipe statment.
What is the proper way of testing these mergeMap pattern?

Comment: Include the unit test code you have so far in your post.

Comment: You have to mock the `Chassis` result & spy on `http.get().pipe()` using that mock. Then you can validate the return by simply subscribing to the spy.

Comment: Can you include the test code that you have so far? Also, why are you using `mergeMap` rather than just `map` and then removing the `of`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you should be using [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap). You should check that.

Here's how I test a function from a service that makes a HTTP request and returns observable.

## 1 - Mock HTTP client

This is an example of how I do it in an Angular project, using `TestBed` to inject dependencies.

```js
let httpClient: HttpClient;
let service: YourService;
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        ...
        }).compileComponents();
    httpClient = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    service = TestBed.get(YourService);
});
```

## 2 - Spy the mock function

To ensure the get request returns what you want, you must spy it and provide a fake result.

```js
describe("WHEN: getAllChassis", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const RESPONSE_MOCK = of(
      new HttpResponse({
        body: {
          /* whatever your service returns */
        },
      })
    );
    spyOn(httpClient, "get").and.returnValue(RESPONSE_MOCK);
  });

  // Here will go your test
});
```

## 3 - Check your function result

To test your feature, check that it returns what you expect (considering we know what the http.get will return).

Note that I am using `done` as this is an async function. The test will not end until done is called (or timeout).

```js
it("THEN: should return data", (done) => {
  getAllChassis()
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual({
        /* what you expect in result */
      });
      done();
    });
});
```